# How to position nav element center under parent div?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, resize, css-position, nav

I've added a second `nav` element to a view, under the site banner. But when the screen is expanded at it's default resolution, the menu is skewed to the left of the site banner.

My aim is to position the menu directly under in line with the site banner. I made a new **[JSFiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/brianVarley/m7h541vb/)** of the page setup to explain the current positioning issue.

I did inspect with Chrome dev tools and it look like a padding causing the positioning highlighted in orange:

[image]
The menu currently appears of center like this:

[image]

Whereas I want position it directly under the "Self Service" div like this:

[image]

I've tried reducing the right margin on the nav element's custom CSS in order to push in further right in line with the banner:

```
#chartNav {
    background-color: #614767;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 10px 20px 10px 20px;
    margin: 0 5% 0 10%;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    text-align: center;


}
```

But the nav menu is still pulling off center of the banner.

**Question:**

How can I position a nav element center under parent div?

This is a gist of the markup containing the banner site title div and it's containing nav menu:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="col-md-2 col-xs-2"></div>
        <div class="col-md-10 col-xs-6">
            <label class="main-title">Self Service</label>
        </div>

        <div class="row">


            <div class="col">

                <div class="col">

                    <nav>

                        <ul id="chartNav">
                            <li><a>Asset Selection:</a></li>
                            <li>
                                <a>All <span class="arrow">&#9660</span></a>
                                <ul class="sub-menu">
                                    <li><a href="#" class="small" data-value="option1" tabindex="-1"><input type="checkbox" />&nbsp;Option 1</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#" class="small" data-value="option2" tabindex="-1"><input type="checkbox" />&nbsp;Option 2</a></li>

                                </ul>
                            </li>
                            <li><a>Date Range:</a></li>
                            <li>
                                <input class="input-sm" type="text" name="daterange" value="01/01/2015 - 01/31/2015" />
                            </li>
                            <li><a>Profile:</a></li>
                            <li>
                                <a>Default <span class="arrow">&#9660</span></a>
                                <ul class="sub-menu">
                                    <li><a href="#" class="small" data-value="option1" tabindex="-1"><input type="checkbox" />&nbsp;Option 1</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#" class="small" data-value="option2" tabindex="-1"><input type="checkbox" />&nbsp;Option 2</a></li>

                                </ul>
                            </li>
                        </ul>

                    </nav>

                </div>
            </div>               

        </div>

</div>
```

Comment: corrected the JSFiddle link..

Comment: center means what? can you desc in more detail plz.

Comment: @NikVarma added some images above to explain. Now the menu is off to the left of the site banner, but it should be directly under the "Self Service" banner.

Comment: Plz try removing the margin or margin:0 7% 0 0% from #chartNav, if just you have to make this much then

Comment: When I remove the margin, the menu sticks to the left side of the browser. Any other ideas?

Comment: Not really familiar with the bootstrap but here's a fiddle for you https://jsfiddle.net/VilleKoo/2rbhxcx5/1/

You can find the edits in the bottom of the css. Also note that i removed those .col divs that you don't really need.

Comment: See here updated fiddle ; 

https://jsfiddle.net/m7h541vb/2/

Comment: In Bootstrap you can use `.col-*-offset-*` to specify that a column should be pushed to the left X grid items.  For example `.col-md-offset-3` would be ideal in your situation.  You would need to re-do a lot of your CSS though, because much of your styles are written in such a way that they break the Bootstrap grid sizings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding this seems to solve the issue, the first two lines align the nav's container to the center, while the third removes that unnecessary left margin that you mentioned.

```
.col-md-10{  
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    margin-left: 0px;
}
```

check it out https://jsfiddle.net/m7h541vb/3